# Passing parameter to function in ng-repeat by ng-click

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

Hi I have a problem with passing in ng-repeat parameters in function by ng-click.
My tr in ng-repeat is:

```
<tr ng-repeat="generalSurvey in surveys">
    <td>
       <% generalSurvey.survey.trans_id %>
    </td>
    <td>
       <% generalSurvey.survey.created_at | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' %>
    </td>
    <td>
       <% generalSurvey.save_answers_date | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' %>
    </td>
    <td>
       <% generalSurvey.survey.base_survey.name %>
    </td>
    <td>
       <% generalSurvey.survey.status.name %>
    </td>
    <td>
       <div ng-click = "editCase( {{ generalSurvey.caseData.caseId  }} )"><% generalSurvey.caseData.caseId %></div>
    </td>
    <td>
       <% generalSurvey.caseData.firstContact %>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Below I show code of my directive:

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.surveys = {};

    scope.getSurveys = function () {
        surveysClient.getAll(function (callback) {
            scope.surveys = callback.data;
            console.log(scope.surveys);
        });
    };
    // Pobranie danych o ankietach
    scope.getSurveys();
    scope.editCase = function (selectedCase) {
       CicCase.get(parseInt(selectedCase), function (callback) {
            console.log("siema");
       });
    }
},
```

Error which I I'm seeing now is: 
[image]

How could I pass this param correctly?

Comment: You don't have to use curly braces {{}} in your ng-click ng-click = "editCase( generalSurvey.caseData.caseId   )

Answer (score 3):

The `ng-click` for

```
ng-click = "editCase( {{ generalSurvey.caseData.caseId  }} )"
```

should be written as

```
ng-click = "editCase( generalSurvey.caseData.caseId )"
```

With no expression syntax `{{}}`

Comment: Here is a problem, beacuse when I have written: <div ng-click = "editCase( generalSurvey.caseData.caseId )"><% generalSurvey.caseData.caseId %></div> then result is: <div ng-click="editCase( generalSurvey.caseData.caseId )" class="ng-binding">232581</div>

Comment: what do you get the parameter value inside the function editCase in controller?

Comment: My data are being downloaded from server in AngularJS directive , next they are saved in scope.surveys = callback.data; in callback function.